# Why my program doesn't count whitespaces and tabs correctly? Can it be an error in the compiler?

Tags: c

I was doing an exercise of the Kernighan & Ritchie book (Write a program to count blanks, tabs, and newlines) and my program seems correct comparing with the answers that I found on internet, but sometimes it outputs some gigantic numbers for blanks and it doesn't count tabs, can someone help me?

Also, I have another issue: I program on a Chromebook using Linux and most examples of this book in the chapter use EOF to stop the program, but when I use this command my program don't run the rest of the code, so I have to use another way to stop the program but if someone could explain to me how can I resume the program after press Ctrl+Z it would be great.

```
int main(void)
{

    int input = 0;
    int blanks = 0;
    int tabs = 0;
    int lines = 0;

    while(input != '*')
    {
        input = getchar();
        switch(input)
        {
            case '\n':
                lines++;
            case ' ':
                blanks++;
            case '\t':
                tabs++;
            default:
                break;

        }
    }
    printf("BLANKS:%i TABS:%i LINES:%i", blanks, tabs, lines);
    return 0;
}
```

Example of output:

```
tab     tab     newline
blank blank end* 
BLANKS:3 TABS:5 LINES:1
```

It doesn't make sense for me.

Comment: @PM77-1 What's wrong with that?

Comment: You don't have `break` after each case. If it's a new line it get counted for all.

Comment: good that you're doing the exercise to see how it works, but for future reference using [`isspace`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/isspace) is the preferred method instead of rolling your own.

Comment: also, "it doesn't count tabs" isn't a symptom of omitting the `break` statements. Do you mean "it doesn't count tabs [correctly]", or do you have input with tabs where your code reports 0 tabs? If so, you'll need to elaborate on that more, providing the input at least.

Comment: @gusfring alves, Tip: save time and enable all compiler warnings.  Faster than posting on SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing breaks from your switch statement

```
        case '\n':
            lines++;
            break;
        case ' ':
            blanks++;
            break;
        case '\t':
            tabs++;
            break;
```

If you don't use a `break` then one case will fall through to the next one, so a newline character would count as a newline, a blank and a tab, for example.

PS It is never an error in the compiler.

Comment: I wasn't fast enough.

Comment: lol it was so basic and i didn't pay attention, thank you! i'm curious, why it is never an error in the compiler?

Comment: @gusfringalves Sometimes it is useful to "fall through". For example in [Duff's device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device). In everyday code it happens from time to time that you actually want to "fall through". So the compiler can't know if it was intentional or not.

Comment: @gusfringalves You write code that falls through all the time, e.g. `case 1: case 2: case 3: printf("here\n");`. Cases 1 and 2 are falling through to case 3.